# How to filter category list by custom product attribute in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I have two different headers in my Magento one for retail shop and second is for commercial shop in same store view. In both header Product category will be same.

- Condition #1 :- In retail shop when we click on "Products" category then it will be list all products.
- Condition #2 :- when I will change click on commercial shop header then it will be show only commercial products I have assigned custom attribute for it.
  Is this possible ?

I found code for loaded product collection in this file \app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List.php can we add attribute filter in this function ?

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
            $layer = $this->getLayer();
            /* @var $layer Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer */
            if ($this->getShowRootCategory()) {
                $this->setCategoryId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId());
            }

            // if this is a product view page
            if (Mage::registry('product')) {

                // get collection of categories this product is associated with
                $categories = Mage::registry('product')->getCategoryCollection()
                    ->setPage(1, 1)
                    ->load();

                // if the product is associated with any category
                if ($categories->count()) {
                    // show products from this category
                    $this->setCategoryId(current($categories->getIterator()));
                }
            }

            $origCategory = null;
            if ($this->getCategoryId()) {
                $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getCategoryId());
                if ($category->getId()) {
                    $origCategory = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
                    $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
                    $this->addModelTags($category);
                }
            }
            $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();

            $this->prepareSortableFieldsByCategory($layer->getCurrentCategory());

            if ($origCategory) {
                $layer->setCurrentCategory($origCategory);
            }
        }

        return $this->_productCollection;
    }
```

Comment: You can also refer the link where Sorting of product by attributes. http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-products/sort-show-products-by-sold-quantity-in-magento/ Help of above example you can add you own attribute.

Comment: Can you find the way to filter product collection on layered navigation and category page using attribute,if you find than please post it...

Comment: @ND17 have you tried below mentioned Piyush's code ?

Comment: yes but its only filter in category page not in layered navigation and toolbar  is also not given correct item

Comment: have you tried it in toolbar.php public function setCollection($collection)() ??

Comment: Yes in that i am getting correct collection but they are use getSize() so that i can't get proper item if i change it to count() than it will give correct answer. but after than i m stuck in layered navigation how to apply that filter in layered navigation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your second Condition you can Filter Your Product Collection Like This :-

```
$products=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('your_custom_attribute_code', 'your_custom_attribute_value');
```

You Can Add this filter at File list.php

`app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List.php`
Find The `setCollection` method

and under `$this->_productCollection = $collection;`

add this code

`$collection->addAttributeToFilter('your_custom_attribute_code', 'your_custom_attribute_value');`

Comment: I think it's `addAttributeToFilter` for product collections, not `addFieldToFilter`.

Comment: @Piyush I know this type filter but i need it done in product list so it will also apply on layer navigation see my updated question.

Comment: @Arunendra you can apply this filter on `setCollection` method of block file.

Comment: @Piyush you mean in list.phtm can you show me query for it.

Comment: @Arunendra I have updated the answer.

Comment: @Piyush it's not working thanks for your support